# What does "위해" mean here? Not "harm" or "benefit"

Tags: translation, meaning

What does "위해" mean in the below text?

I'm trying to translate [a post on O.LAB's Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/1871286686267401/photos/a.1979044285491640/2091983740864360/?type=3&theater).  Here is the first sentence:

> ## 근본주의
>
> 본래 다양한 형태의
>   극보수적-반근대적 운동들을
>   폭넓게 가리키기 위해 사용되는 용어.

I'm just a beginner.  This is the most complex thing I've attempted so far.  I had to look up most of the words, and eventually I cheated and just used Google Translate, which got me on the right track:

> ## Fundamentalism
>
> A term used to broadly denote various conservative-anti-modern movements in nature.

So I think I understand the purpose and meaning of all of the words in there now, except for 위해.  Here, it does not seem to mean...

- [harm, injury, hazard, danger, peril](https://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=en&entryId=efe125e8c6ad493d9e21340a45fdb85b&query=%EC%9C%84%ED%95%B4)
- [care for, take (good) care of](https://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=en&entryId=d77b84286eeb4e6eae3c377dd51aa289&query=%EC%9C%84%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4)

What does this word mean here?

Comment: 위해 = 위하여 ->  in order to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-기 위해(서) here means "to"/"in order to".

When you attach -기 위해(서) to verbs, it becomes "to + verb".

For example :

> 채소를 사기 위해(서) 시장에 갔다.

(I went to the market **to buy** vegetables).

> 책을 빌리기 위해(서) 도서관에 갈 것이다.

(I'm going to go to the library **to borrow** a book).

You can also attach 위해(서) to nouns as well. When you do this, you don't need to add -기. You add 을/를 instead.

More :
I wrote the -서 inside (  ) because they are, most of the time, omitted.